# How can I fetch my data from inside my JSON array?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to fetch each text for each step and the text that belongs to it. Here is my HTML (which includes my javascript):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="art-title-boxes"></div>
<script>
var divContain = document.getElementById("art-title-boxes");
        fetch('article-template.json')
            .then(function (response) { 
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                addCatData(data);
            });
        function addCatData(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.className = "art-name-box";
                div.innerHTML = data[i].cnct-a.step;
                divContain.appendChild(div);
               var div2 = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = data[i].cnct-a.text;
                divContain.appendChild(div);          
            }}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript code is based off this article: https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/
Here is the content of my .JSON file:

```
{
"cnct-a":   [ 
    {
        "step": "1",
        "text": "XXX"
    },    
    {
        "step": "2",
        "text": "XXX"
    },    
    {
        "step": "3",
        "text": "XXX"
    }
],
"cnct-b": [

    {
        "step": "1",
        "text": "XXX"
    },    
    {
        "step": "2",
        "text": "XXX"
    },    
    {
        "step": "3",
        "text": "XXX"
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: theres multiple objects in properties, not an array. look up `Object.keys`

Comment: Use (for ... of) and cnct-a is probably an invalid variable name so if you want to reference it. Use it by string myjson["cnct-a"].